# Printing new line in RTF file made with Python

Tags: python, rtf

I have made a GUI program where I can enter some values in various fields. All info from these fields is then combined into a dictionary, which is then stored using the shelve module. With the push of a button, I can then export all dictionary entries into an RTF file, as I want parts of the file formatted in italics.

The GUI and shelve part of the program works just fine. The problem I'm having is exporting multiple lines to the RTF file. When I print the strings I want to write to the RTF file into the python shell, I get multiple lines. But when I export it to RTF, it's all printed on one line. I know this should usually be fixed by adding an \n to the string, but this hasn't worked for me in any way. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or maybe a workaround where I can still use italics to save the text?

As far as a working example goes:

```
data = dict()
data['first'] = {'author': 'Kendall MA'
                 'year': '1987',
                 'title': 'This is a test title'}
data['second'] = {'author': 'Mark',
                  'year': '2014',
                  'title': 'It is not working correctly'}
rtf = open('../test.rtf', 'w')
rtf.write(r'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Cambria;}}')

for key in data.keys():
    entry = data[key]
    rtf.write(r'{0} ({1}): \i {2} \i0'.format(entry['author'], entry['year'], entry['title']) + '\n')
rtf.write(r'}\n\x00')
rtf.close()
```

The output this code gives is:

Mark (2014): *It is not working correctly* Kendall (1987): *This is a test title*

While it should be:

Mark (2014): *It is not working correctly*

Kendall (1987): *This is a test title*

EDIT:
I found out that the combination of /line and /par works. Using them seperately does not for some reason that is unclear to me (maybe somebody can explain?).

But a new error occurred. When the author is in fact multiple authors, which I enter by list (['Kendall MA', 'Powsen RB']) and then make into a single string using ', '.join(entry['author']), the first word gets cut off. So I would get
'MA, Powsen RB' instead of 'Kendall MA, Powsen RB'. Does anyone know why and how to counter it?

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary to zero-terminate a plain text file (which is what an RTF file is)...

Answer (score 2):

`\n` has no special meaning in RTF. If you want to output a line break, you will need to use `r'\line'` or `r'\par'` for a paragraph break instead of (or in addition to, for readability) `\n`.

Comment: Literal newlines are also allowed. From Microsoft's reference: "A carriage return (character value 13) or linefeed (character value 10) will be treated as a \par control if the character is preceded by a backslash. You must include the backslash; otherwise, RTF ignores the control word." (I looked it up to check if they get converted to spaces or not, and it's an interesting addition.)